# Create date-table in DB-Fiddle or SQL-Fiddle with all days of a year

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8060763f4abf624a817a8ac6d8893136)**

```
CREATE TABLE dates (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    date DATE
);

INSERT INTO dates
(date)
VALUES 
('2020-01-01'),
('2020-01-02'),
('2020-01-03'),
('2020-01-04'),
('2020-01-05'),
('2020-01-06'),
('2020-01-07'),
('2020-12-29'),
('2020-12-30'),
('2020-12-31');
```

---

For example tables in `DB-Fiddle` or `SQL-Fiddle` I would like to create a table with all dates in one year. 
Instead of adding 365 days manually I am wondering if there is way to add them automatically?

Comment: `insert into dates (date) select generate_series ('2020-01-01'::date, '2020-12-31'::date, interval '1 day')`

Comment: @Hambone: I tried your soluton but it gives me an error: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=58f2fea4255c2683f0160323e48d2ba8

Comment: You caught me pre-edit...  add the (date) before the "select"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9a008cda9247040f68e1ec29adef3aff)**

**Option 1:** Generate Date Series directly into table

```
CREATE TABLE dates (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    date DATE
);

INSERT INTO dates 
(date) 
SELECT generate_series ('2020-01-01'::date, '2020-12-31'::date, interval '1 day');
```

**Option 1:** Generate Date Series in a query

```
SELECT 
date_trunc('day', date_list)::date AS date
FROM generate_series
('2020-01-01'::timestamp, '2020-12-31'::timestamp, interval '1 day') date_list;
```